# Django Rest Framework - Add object with foreign key data in path param

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models, representing an author his articles, the idea is an author can add articles freely (not that it matters for my problem, but in an append only matter).

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = ...


class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='articles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = ...
    content = ...
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

My serializes are as follows:

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

And I have a simple view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def author_articles(request, author_id):
    try:
        author = Author.objects.get(id=author_id)
    except Author.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        articles = author.articles.all()
        serializer = serializers.ArticlesSerializer(articles, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = serializers.ArticlesSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Where the Url is defined:

```
url(r'^authors/(?P<author_id>[0-9]+)/articles/$', views.author_articles)
```

So a simple POST request to the URL: `server:port/authors/1/articles/` with the body below works like a charm!

```
{
    "author": 1,
    "title":  "foo",
    "content": "bar"
}
```

What bugs me is that I provide the author id twice, once in the body and once in the path params. I can easily remove it from the path param and make it work, but what I really want is the opposite. I want the body to be without the id, and the id deduced from the path param.

I tried many many ways, and failed repeatedly. Would appreciate help.

I am using Django and Django-Rest-Framework over Postgres.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass `author_id` to serializer `save()` method:

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = serializers.ArticlesSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(author=author.id)
```

One advice, Django Rest Framework allows you write less more code. You don't need regular Django views with `JSONParser`, `JsonResponse` etc.
Use `APIView` class or `api_view` decorator instead or even use `viewsets` it can reduce the function lines to 5-6

Comment: The first option I tried myself before posting the question and it doesn't work . But the second - works like a charm thank you! Re-decorators and viewsets I started out with viewsets and failed, so decided to start with the basics to understand how it works and now that I have a working version I can try and upgrade it.